# Run jhipster-registry in production

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jhipster

This is a continuation of my previous question about running a [jhipster microservices application on AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544921/jhipster-docker-compose-deploy-to-aws).

I've used `docker-machine` to create a new VM with Docker installed.

I have setup docker registry, and pushed my images to it, as well as logged into this registry on the AWS-VM.

I attempted to copy the contents of the `/docker-composer` directory I generated using `yo jhipster:docker-compose` and attempted to run:

`docker-compose up -d`

But I receive the error:

```
ubuntu@aws-test:~/docker-compose$ sudo docker-compose up
Unsupported config option for services service: 'jhipster-registry'
```

I can manually run the jhipster-registry with docker, but as there are many other underlying services I'd prefer to create a production `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using an older version of `docker-compose` that doesn't support the V2 format. You need to upgrade to at least 1.6.2 (but 1.7.0 is currently the latest).

Comment: Thanks guys! That was the key! I didn't have time to respond last night ... but I don't know how I managed to get the wrong version `docker-compose` installed ):

Answer (score 0):

Aside of your `docker-compose.yml` you should have the `jhipster-registry.yml` and the `elk.yml` files, if one of those files are not present it won't work because the docker-compose file is looking for those files.

If you want to have all in one file you have to copy the `jhipster-registry` service in `jhipster-registry.yml` into your `docker-compose.yml`.